# CSV file w/ two different timestamp formats in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

(Submitting on behalf of a Snowflake User)

---

I have a csv file that has two different timestamp format.

For example:

- time_stmp1:  `2019-07-01 00:03:17.000 EDT`
- time_stmp2:  `2019-06-30 21:03:17 PDT`

In the copy command I am able to specify only one format.
How should I proceed to load both columns in TIMESTAMP_LTZ data type?

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Snowflake does not allow loading data with different date formats from one single file.

If the data in the file is just date, then use datatype as the date and, in FILE FORMAT, define date as AUTO.

If the data is included date and time, then use the datatype as timestamp and define timestamp in the FILE FORMAT as per the data file.
DATE_FORMAT = 'AUTO' TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'

If there are multiple date formats  in the file, for example, MM/DD/YY and MM/DD/YY HH:MI: SS, it does not load correctly, you may need to split the file and load separately or update all data(date type) to a single common format and load it to the table.

Answer (score 2):

you could use the SELECT form of COPY INTO where you transform the date fields individually, something like:

```
COPY INTO MY_TABLE (NAME, DOB, DOD, HAIR_COLOUR) 
FROM (
   SELECT $1, TO_DATE($2,'YYYYMMDD'), TO_DATE($3,'MM-DD-YYYY'), $4 
   FROM @MY_STAGE/mypeeps (file_format => 'MY_CSV_FORMAT') 
)
ON_ERROR = CONTINUE;
```